# run-time where clauses in pyodbc - ERROR:non-boolean type where condition is expected

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

My architect just dumped those part of the queries which needs to be used as part of building another query involving the "where" clause ,into the database..
My job, as a developer is to fetch those queries and suffix those queries to the where clause to build another query.

What I have in database -

```
(Sector is not null)
```

How I am building my queries after fetching the above contents from the database:-

```
def user_configuration(cnxn = cnxn, sql_where = 'sector IS NOT NULL',  ):
        cursor3 = cnxn.cursor()
        try:
            sql_select = "SELECT * FROM dbo.inputs_userinputdata where  "

            sql_select += sql_where
            cursor3.execute(sql_select)


#function call - note sql_where is generated during runtime by querying
def sector_configuration(cnxn = cnxn , portfolioId = 1):
    cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute("SELECT sector_sql FROM dbo.portfolio_definition_portfoliodata where portfolio_id = "+str(portfolioId))
    while 1:
        row = cursor1.fetchone()
        return row.sector_sql
sql_where = sector_configuration(cnxn, portfolioId=1) #here 'sector is not null' is returned during run-time
user_configuration(cnxn,sql_where)
```

I am getting the error message : -

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'sector is not null'. (4145) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

May I know where I go wrong? Do I need to implement something like dynamic SQL queries or stored procedures? I am fairly new to the IT world.

I wanted to fetch the results from the database after running through the 'sql_select' query.
Instead I ran into the 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'. Suppressing the error was a futile attempt.

Comment: print the built query, eyeball it! If you like try running it via phpMyAdmin to see if it works or not

Comment: Don't build SQL strings like this. I'd recommend using something like SQLAlchemy's Core to build the query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes, when I pass the query as compile-time query, I could extract the results. But, I get errors when the same 'query string' is extracted during the run-time query building exercise

Comment: You should ask someone on your team about safely defining dynamic SQL queries; you are in need of some training.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Barmar, edited the code example in the minimal reproducible way

Comment: @chepner, I am a mechanical engineer. Switched recently to IT/business consulting to pay the bills

Comment: That MRE is not reproducible since you haven't shown the value of `sql_where` in the caller.

Comment: You can reproduce by having a sample database table with a row that has 'sector is not null' in one of its columns. Then fetch the results using SELECT query. Feed the results that has content 'sector is not null' into the 'sql_where'. Basically, like a run-time instantiation

Comment: Added the line of code where the run-time instantiation of sql_where takes place